# How to customize cluster icon using gmaps4rails

Tags: gmaps4rails

So we're trying to change the default cluster icon using gmaps for rails. 
In the [wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Markers)
it says

```
You can customize the pics used by the clusterer by setting the Gmaps.map.customClusterer js function in your code.
```

Where would we put that function? It says "In the javascript" - but where? Do we straight-up edit the code generated by gmaps4rails? How does gmaps4rails pick up the information?

Answer (score 0):

To do this customization you just need to create js file. Then you can 
"require" that js file in your Application.js or otherwise just directly refer in your view file. That's it you need not to do anything else. I have used it and it worked for me. If any questions do let me know.

To understand how it works you can just refer the

```
gmaps4rails.base.js (see  @customClusterer = -> false) 
gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js (method - createClusterer)
```

it is straight forward to understand

Comment: What about version ```2.1.2```, as ```@customClusterer``` and ```createClusterer``` is nowhere to be found.

Comment: @Cacofonix I think gmap4rails [documentation](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Customized-Cluster-Icons) will help you